# How to fix error that related to Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, pentaho

This really make me stress. I try to make connection between Pentaho and database SQL Server 2000 so many time. Every time I try to connect using Native (JDBC) access, this error always come out:

```
Code:
Error connecting to database [sutera] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database


Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.




org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database


Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the    sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.




at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:415)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:353)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:306)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:294)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:84)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2459)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:541)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:139)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:123)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:26)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:121)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:375)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:301)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:115)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:62)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.editConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:88)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:2900)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.access$2300(Spoon.java:332)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$27.widgetDefaultSelected(Spoon.java:5657)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1227)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7368)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8673)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the  sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:542)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:399)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE)   version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which   provides support for JDBC 4.0.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:518)
... 45 more


Hostname       : 172.16.1.133
Port           : 1521
Database name  : kjc_v2
```

I search the reason why I got this error and what I found that I think it maybe the causes of this problem is beacause of my Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7. From the research I made, this Java version cannot read jdbc driver that I use. So I download other jdbc driver that I think it suitable for sql server 2000. But same error still come out. So, I change my plan. I try to change my JRE to other version. But the problem is even I already change JRE to other version, it still detect same version and same error still come out every time I test the connection.

Please someone guide me how to remove this error? I'm new in Pentaho & when facing something like this, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Was the other JDBC driver you tried sqljdbc4.jar, or was it something else?

Comment: I tried sqljdbc4.jar and I also tried jdbc driver from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/.

Comment: When moving to Java7, there is a different jar for the SQL Server jdbc driver.  This article, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx explains some of this.   Sounds like your classpath still has the older, sqljdbc.jar on the path BEFORE the sqljdbc4.jar driver.   This should work fairly easily.  You might want to break it down to a very small test case just to prove it to yourself first.

Comment: how & where I can change the classpath?